# import specific columns using scan() in R

Tags: r

I want to scan a large CSV file into R. It is a bzip format and I don't wish to decompress it in order to read it in.

It has dimension 3 million rows * 400 columns.

I am trying to read it in row-chunks (of 2000 rows at) but only need the first 5 columns.

My sample code is:

```
tot_impt_rows <- 2000
x <- scan(file = file.path(ps_wdir, ps_sourcedata_dir, "test.csv.bz2")
     , what = c(rep("", 5), rep(NULL, 395))
     , skip = 6
     , nlines = tot_impt_rows
     , sep = ",")
```

The above code does not subset to the first 5 columns i.e. imports all 400 columns in the scan.

I am trying to use the "what" feature in scan() to only keep specific columns (in this case columns 1:5)?

Could anyone explain how to read in **specific column indices** with scan() on the fly (not just the first 5 columns). It will greatly speed up the import procedure.

Comment: [link](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Scanning-only-specific-columns-into-R-from-a-VERY-large-file-td2013646.html) http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Scanning-only-specific-columns-into-R-from-a-VERY-large-file-td2013646.html

Comment: Thanks but that approach uses read.table not scan(). Could you please explain how to do it with scan()?

Comment: I think you should have a look at `data.table::fread()`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest unzipping the data and using fread from data.table  to skip the columns you do not want:

```
Dataset<-fread(data, sep="," , header=FALSE,
colClasses=c(rep("numeric",5), rep("NULL",495)))
```

Comment: Thanks - however as per my question I don't have the hard disk space to decompress this file entirely hence trying to read it in uncompressed mode as efficiently as possible.